# How can I extract the first paragraph of a PDF document using Perl's CAM::PDF?

Tags: perl, pdf, extract

How can I extract the first paragraph of a PDF document using Perl's [CAM::PDF](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/CAM::PDF)?

Answer (score 1):

```
print CAM::PDF->new('file.pdf')->getPageText(1);
```

will get you all of the text from the page.  But, CAM::PDF is definitely not the best tool for this particular job (I'm the author).  I added text extraction as a whim just to see if I could do it.

Answer (score 0):

Plain PDF really is not a markup language. Text is drawn at specific locations. There is something called [Tagged PDF](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Acrobat/9.0/Standard/WS4A3903C4-FD2A-4ca4-A3C3-3FFEB1C7AD3B.html) and if your documents are tagged, your job might be easier.

I would be inclined to run the documents through a PDF to text translator and grab the first chunk of text out of that if text is stored as text in your PDF and not images.